# Change the owner of a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to write code which can establish a new owner and remove the old one for a document, I have already written code where I add a new editor, but the function `setOwner()` does not work. Find below the code I have written with the help of the Google Apps Script documentation.

```js
function folderOps(){ 

   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Document link comes here'); 

   folder.addEditor('email');
   folder.setOwner('email');
   folder.removeEditor('email'); 
}
```

Comment: Can you do it from the drive web interface  on this folder ?

Comment: I think that applies to files or folders that were shared with you.  In that case you can change the owner to you and then you essentially own your own copy of the file or folder and it's no longer shared with the previous owner.  This [link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893?visit_id=1-636377329293472363-2260195062&p=disable_download&hl=en&rd=1#disable) talks about it a bit.

Comment: Dont think this is possible if the file is not related with you in any way (shared). You trying to grab some random folder and change ownership? xD